# What can I use to let users build their own avatar character?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would you go about providing users with the ability to build a custom avatar character, something like [Yahoo! Avatars](http://messenger.yahoo.com/features/avatars/)?

**EDIT** - Let me be more specific about what Yahoo! Avatars does:
It lets you *create* an avatar by selecting a face, hair style, eyes, etc.
This is what I'm looking for.

I am interested in:

- Libraries, free or paid
- Outsourcing to an external website, provided this can be well integrated into our website
- Any other suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also [My Avatar Editor](http://www.myavatareditor.com/) which makes Wii-style (and Wii-compatible) avatars. It's Flash based and it's [on googlecode with a MIT-license](http://code.google.com/p/myavatareditor/).

Comment: This is great and exactly what I'm looking for. To bad it is in Flash and I'm a Microsoft programmer - a Silverlight version would be awesome. I might still give it a go.

Answer (score 5):

There are many web sites that let users build "cartoon character" or 3D rendered characters for avatars, but most sites don't allow users to use those avatars on other web sites.  This one does: http://www.moeruavatar.com/index_en.shtml, but it's up to the user to save the generated image and upload it to other web sites.  I don't know of any ready-made libraries of code you can install on your server to get such functionality on your own web site.

Suggestions for general avatar image / userid or email association:

1. Gravatar.  http://en.gravatar.com/
2. Identicon: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon, http://identicon.codeplex.com/
3. Wavatar
4. MonsterId

Gravatar is a web service.  Identicon is an algorithm you can implement locally on your server if you prefer.  The last two are kinda funny but I don't think I'd ever use them.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I have not been specific enough. I'd like users to be able to **build** their avatar character by selecting hair style, eyes, etc.. I don't think Gravatar or the other ones you mentioned do that.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.moeruavatar.com/index_en.shtml  Users can compose their avatar character, then download the finished image to use wherever they want, such as uploading to Gravatar or your site.  Seems to be more open than some of the other avatar builder sites that come up in a Google search.

Answer (score 0):

Try a Globally Recognized Avatar, or Gravatar.

http://en.gravatar.com/

Allows users to register and site developers to access Gravitars.

Answer (score 0):

Gravatar.com
deviantart.com
MonsterId
www.dressupgames.com/avatars

Good luck!